# Is there a way in Django to get the currently authenticated user directly from a model?

Tags: python, django, authentication, model

Like if I have a Message model like

```
class Message(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User)
    to = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_authenticated_user_inbox_messages(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(to=authenticated_user).all()
```

**authenticated_user** being a way to get the currently authenticated user.

In the view, I can get the authenticated user with *request.user*

But, if I don't want or can't by design to pass this as a parameter, is there a way to get it directly from inside the model?

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A Model object exists independently from a web request. For example, you can define a management command that uses model objects from the command-line, where there is no request.

What I've seen as a good practice is to define a static method on your Model object that takes a User object as input, like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User)
    to = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    @staticmethod
    def get_messages_to(user):
        return Message.objects.filter(to=user)

    @staticmethod
    def get_messages_from(user):
        return Message.objects.filter(from=user)
```

You could also define a custom manager for the model and define these convenience methods there instead.

**EDIT:** Okay, technically it is possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing it. For a method, see [Global Django Requests](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you connect the set up a foreign key from Messages to Users, django automatically creates a related field on the User model instances. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

So, if you have a user object, you should be able to access `user_object.messages.all()`.  This feels like a more django-appropriate way to do what your `get_authenticated_user_inbox_messages()` method is doing.

Comment: Yes, but in the situation I have described I don't have the user object. Thats the whole point =D

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by the accepted answer then. The static methods proposed both require that you pass in the user as an argument.

Comment: Okay, technically it is possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing it. For a method, see Global Django Requests.

Comment: your view would have a user though, so you access it from there; i.e. request.user.message_set.all()